# RMI only a base technology or still worth to use

Tags: java, network-programming, rmi

My question is if RMI as a standard Java Network technology is
worth to use in modern applications.

Since there are so many sophisticated technologies like WebServices (SOAP/Rest) or EJBs
or Message Orientated technologies does it make sense to use the standard RMI mechanism to use within an own application.

I know that RMI is the base for modern technolgoies EJB (RMI-IIOP) and so on
but it is still possible to use this technology on it's own.

I see the main advantage in the lesser complexisity contrary to Web or Application Servers in order to build simple distributed applications.

The main disadadvantage in my point of view is RMIRegistry and the legacy behaviour of this kind of mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you summed it up pretty nicely already. If you just want to execute classes remotely, it's fine, e.g. for simple commandline client/server things or distributed computing.

Comment: i don't wanted to give the answer within my question. I intended to raise some kind of discussion.

Comment: You probably could also add Corba to the discussion, then. As it is probably closer to RMI than the Webservices etc. are. I think the main point is whether you decide if your application should be run on a tomcat, normal apache or just has to work with only the jvm. Maybe on devices with very limited memory RMI could show it's strenghts...

Comment: Yes your are completely right. That was my itention. It was my first SO question. I think i will close it in a sec there are already 4 close votes because it more a political question than a technical. But you really show some nice advantages of RMI.